# Pandas dataframe drop duplicates based in another column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-munging, drop-duplicates

I have a dataframe with duplicates:

```
timestamp id ch is_eval. c
  12.     1.  1.  False. 2
  13.     1.  0.  False. 1
  12.     1.  1.  True.  4
  13.     1   0.  False. 3
```

When there are duplicated, it is always when
I want to `drop_duplicates` with the key `(timestamp,id,ch)` but keep the row where  `is_eval` is True.
Meaning, if there is a row with `is_eval==True` then keep it. Otherwise, it doesnt matter.
So the output here should be:

```
  12.     1.  1.  True.  4
  13.     1   0.  False. 1
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.sort_values('is_eval', kind='mergesort', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['timestamp','id','ch'])
print (df)
   timestamp  id  ch  is_eval  c
2         12   1   1     True  4
1         13   1   0    False  1
```